# How to make the animation of the parent div not play in the child div?

Tags: css

I have a simple animation playing in the parent div, but I want it to play it on in the Parent div and not in any of the subsequent child div(s).

I have tried the **animation-play-state** and tried to mess around with the image properties, but no luck so far.

I am using the animation to change the brightness of the image in the parent div which is obviously changing the brightness in the child div.

```css
<style type="text/css">body {
  background-image: url("https://www.ecosia.org/images/?q=ocean%20image#id=73D94E9737B0E809884B687B3BD30B3AE1F46394");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.Main {
  animation-name: Image;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-image: url("https://www.ecosia.org/images/?q=ocean%20image#id=73D94E9737B0E809884B687B3BD30B3AE1F46394");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 99%;
  height: 655px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes Image {
  0% {
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
  50% {
    filter: brightness(160%);
  }
  100% {
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: Black;

}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #096;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3FF;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#0066CC">

  <div class="Main">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is not because the animation is playing on the children of `div.Main`, but because of the nature of how the `filter` property works. The filter is applied as a graphical effect on top of the entire element, including on its children.

You could set your background image to be a separate element on the same level as or underneath your other elements and this would be avoided.

```css
<style type="text/css">* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#image {
  /* Here */
  animation-name: image;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 99%;
  height: 655px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes image {
  0% {
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
  50% {
    filter: brightness(160%);
  }
  100% {
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: Black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #096;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3FF;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#0066CC">

  <div class="main">
    <!-- Here -->
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```